# Is it possible to bind several models to a view with marionette?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

or should I just create one view for each model ? I mean with backbone alone I was doing some kind of "renderSubview" , with marionette this is pointless and I just shoudl avoid this ?

Is it bad to bind a marionette view to several model ? (and update different part of its template according to multiple models update ?)

thansk a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marionette doesn't give you any tools to do exactly that, but it's a thin layer on top of Backbone; the approach you describe will work just fine.

However, if your sub-views are not very simple, it's probably better to use a Marionette `LayoutView`. That way you'll benefit from encapsulation and DOM isolation (so sub-views won't interfere with each others' events).

#### Simple sub-views, Backbone-style

This approach is good for trivial subviews - probably with very simple templates and little user interaction. You don't need anything more than the approach you described:

You can add `renderSubViewX` methods to any Marionette view type (or even a vanilla `Backbone.View`). They'll look like typical Backbone `render` methods - call a template function or create some DOM nodes and insert them into the document. Use `this.listenTo(this.model1, "change", this.renderSubView1, this)` to re-render on changes.

#### LayoutView

If the sub-views are more complex (perhaps they allow non-trivial user interaction) you will benefit from creating a separate `ItemView` for each model. Use a [Marionette `LayoutView`](http://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.4/marionette.layoutview.html) for the parent view.

Derick Bailey's [blog post on Layouts](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/03/22/managing-layouts-and-nested-views-with-backbone-marionette/) is a little out-of-date but provides a good overall introduction.